# Session functionality in application layer?

Tags: spring, security, layer

I'd like my application layer to be aware of which user is logged in to simplify method signatures - for instance method(owner, object) would be simply method(object). I use Spring Security for security though I'd like to keep Spring out of my application layer so there is a separate layer just for that purpose (and DTO conversion) - like a facade (adapter for application services).

How to make the application layer aware of the user context its operating on without using spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to register a `Filter` or `HandlerInterceptor` that would have a look at the `HttpSession` and, if the user is logged in, store some kind of `User` representation in some `static` `ThreadLocal` context. Any class could then have access to this static `ThreadLocal` containing your `User` object.

You would have to remove this object when the user logs out or session expires. Hint: [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html).

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://wiki.openclinica.com/doku.php?id=developerwiki:interceptor)?

Comment: @Kboom Similar. However with that solution, you would have to pass around the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpSession` objects. Instead you should register them in a `static ThreadLocal` which you can then access from any class if you are in the same `Thread`. [This might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784009/why-should-java-threadlocal-variables-be-static).

Comment: Or maybe it would be much easier to just bind SecurityContextHolder.getContext() to that thread local? If I'm wrong correct me please. I'm looking for simplest solution :).

Comment: @Kboom See, I don't know Spring Security, but it seems that `SecurityContextHolder` is exactly what I was describing. If it already offers that, there is no need for you to add anything. Just call that method anywhere you need to check your user.

Comment: One more thing - you said you don't know Spring security. But is it that simple that I could register a listener on session creation / destruction event and bind those to functions from my application layer (for instance logout when session is destroyed) and have security mechanism with no spring security? I could just check what the state of that ThreadLocal variable is to ensure security?

Comment: @kboom Of course you could. That is probably how Spring security is implemented. Careful, a listener is created by the servlet container. You'll need some workarounds if you want to inject Spring beans. But that is a whole other topic.