# Selenium Webdriver TestNG tests are "overwriting" each other

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testng, pageobjects

I am trying to run Selenium Webdriver tests in parallel on a single machine, using TestNG. I have 3 @Test methods, where 3 different users log in to the same application and reach the home page. I need @Test methods to run in parallel, and write to an ExtentReports report.

My problem is, despite 3 completely different methods in different classes, one of the users will be logged into 2 out of 3 of the browsers, leaving a user out.

The login method is located in a PageFactory page object class.

Here are my 3 test methods:

```
@Test(enabled = true, priority = 0) 
public void JohnLogin() throws Exception {
    ExtentTest t = ClientReportFactory.getTest();
    try {       
        Login objLogin = new Login(getDriver());
        String username = "John";
        String password = "Password";
        objLogin.SignIn(username, password);
        HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(getDriver());   
        assertTrue(objHomePage.clientName.getText().c‌​ontains("John"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Test(enabled = true, priority = 1) 
public void BobLogin() throws Exception {
    ExtentTest t = ClientReportFactory.getTest();
    try {       
        Login objLogin = new Login(getDriver());
        String username = "Bob";
        String password = "Password";
        objLogin.SignIn(username, password);
        HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(getDriver());       
        assertTrue(objHomePage.clientName.getText().c‌​ontains("Bob"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Test(enabled = true, priority = 2) 
public void SamLogin() throws Exception {
    ExtentTest t = ClientReportFactory.getTest();
    try {       
        Login objLogin = new Login(getDriver());
        String username = "Sam";
        String password = "Password";
        objLogin.SignIn(username, password);
        HomePage objHomePage = new HomePage(getDriver());       
        assertTrue(objHomePage.clientName.getText().c‌​ontains("Sam"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

So, if I pause the tests on the Homepage. I will have 2 browser windows opened as "John", one "Bob" and no "Sam"... Causing failures.

Here's the PageFactory Object's login method.

```
 public void SignIn(String strUsername, String strPassword) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15); 
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys(strUsername);
    password.clear();
    password.sendKeys(strPassword);
    submit.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(homePagePanel));
}
```

At first I was sure the problem was in the @BeforeMethod threading (As in, the tests were in a different thread than the @Before and @After). But I don't see how that could be the case. The Base Test method successfully opens and closes 3 browsers. It just seems like the @Test methods use each other's data! But just in case, here's my @Before and @After, with my Threading code.

```
public class BaseTest {
    public String browser;
    private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadedDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
@Parameters({ "browser"})
public void setup(String browser)throws MalformedURLException,
InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Internet Explorer")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("MicrosoftEdge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }
        setWebDriver(driver);
        this.browser = browser;
        ClientReportFactory.getTest(ExtentTestName, ExtentTestDescription);

baseURL = "testApp.com";
driver.get(baseURL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

public WebDriver getDriver(){
    return threadedDriver.get();
}
public void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
    threadedDriver.set(driver);
}

@AfterMethod 
public void afterMethod() {
    ClientReportFactory.closeTest(ExtentTestName, ExtentTestDescription);
    getDriver().quit();
    threadedDriver.set(null);
}

@AfterSuite
public void afterSuite() {
    ClientReportFactory.closeReport();
    if (getDriver() != null) {
        getDriver().quit();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Drivers already closed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all of your `@Test` methods are in different classes, I am guessing that the problem is perhaps due to the fact that your `ThreadLocal` variable is **NOT STATIC** but is an instance variable. This causes the behaviour to be **per thread per instance** rather than the desired behaviour viz., **per thread across all instances**. You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784009/why-should-java-threadlocal-variables-be-static) StackOverFlow thread for a better explanation on this.

You would resort to using an instance variant of `ThreadLocal` **if and only if** all your `@Test` methods belong to the same test class (Because now you are only trying to ensure that the class level data member `WebDriver` is shared in a thread safe manner across all the test methods that belong to the same test class)

So if each of your `@Test` methods reside in its own Test class, then please try changing:

```
private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadedDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
```

to

```
private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadedDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
```

Comment: Krishnan, what's wrong in my answer below ? I would like to learn.

Comment: @Dineshmohan - I have fixed the down vote part. On a side note, I think your solution may be plagued by a weird behaviour that Java exhibits when you try to work with ThreadLocals wherein the initialValue() is being defined within a method scope and when that value depends on an enclosing scope. You can read more about it in my blog post https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/a-date-with-threadlocal/ (I don't know for sure if your code will also exhibit the same problem, but it does have the same sort of code which could cause issues)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
public class DriverFactory(){

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driverThread;
public WebDriver driver;

@Parameters("browser")
public WebDriver instantiateDriverObject(String browser) {
DriverFactory factory = new DriverFactory();
driver = factory.createInstance(browser); //Driver instantiation goes here
driverThread = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    protected WebDriver initialValue() {
    webDriverPool.add(driver);
    return driver;
    }
};
return driver;
}

public WebDriver getDriver() {
return driverThread.get();
}
```

}

Comment: I by mistake ended up clicking that. My apologies. Since yesterday I have been trying to fix it but with little luck. I have now fixed it. Sorry for the confusion.